# Vertical text in header cells

Tags: ag-grid

I've been trying to get vertical text in header cells to work properly, but just can't seem to find the winning combination. I've tried to render a custom component, that didn't do it, the closest I've got is applying this css to the relevant header cells:

```
.bool-header {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: left;
    justify-content: left;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
    overflow: overlay;
    .ag-header-cell-text {
        margin-bottom: -15px;
    }
}
```

but I'm still left with it truncating text, and using unnecessary padding, no matter what I set the values to.

Has anyone got a way of making this work? I'm using the react version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, you need to use some styling.

Here you are, the minimum requirements to achieve what you want.

```
.ag-header-cell-label {
  /*Necessary to allow for text to grow vertically*/
  height: 100%;
}

.ag-header-cell-label .ag-header-cell-text {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  -ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;
}
```

[image: Vertical Headers]

Working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/8NeuaQHWQ8TOMXBg?preview

Further reading: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-headers/

Comment: Thanks - only issue is that it makes no difference if I use vertical-lr or vertical-rl (I assume it should read top-bottom vs bottom-top?!)

Comment: Ok got it, should use 'sideways' instead of 'vertical', but that's not always supported. so add: transform: scale(-1)